# returned value is a day later for same code hosted on firebase hosting and firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I am using the code below to find the time in milisec of the monday 00:00:00 of current week.

The code is at two places. in the website built using angular material and hosted on firebase hosting. and in the firebase function. What I am observing is that the value returned on hosting code comes for tuesday 00:00:00 rather monday.

not sure why is the difference when both are running in the same firebase account.

Code:

```
 const date = new Date()
 var begWeek = findDayBegninning(getMonday(date))

function findDayBegninning(date:any){
    const ms = date.getTime();
    const msPerDay = 86400 * 1000;
    return  ms - (ms % msPerDay);
}
```

in firebase function it shows value:
1560124800000

while in hosting it shows
1560211200000

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the difference can be explained by the code running in different time zones.

The code on Firebase Hosting is **not** interpreted by Firebase Hosting in any way, and thus most likely runs on the machine of the user that is visiting the site. That means that the `new Date()` is gotten in the time zone of the visitor's machine.

Code running in Cloud Functions will get a new date in UTC.

Comment: The user is me sitting in north america. and sure that could be a problem for other users. what is the right way to get same mon 00:00:00 from hosting side of code?

Comment: If you want to get the start of the day for the user calling the code, you should pass in the timezone of that user and use that when calculating.

Comment: well to explain a little more:  the firebase db has a node called weekly which has the timestamp using above code for start of every week (mon 00:00:00) 

user on their dashboard can query this data like "weekly scores" at this point the firebase query fetches data  /weekly/<beg of the week> 

So, irrespective of user timezone this key must be same as created via code in firebase trigger function. so how do i always get the same value ?

Comment: You'll have to define the meaning of "weekly". If it has to be the start of the week for each user, then that may be different due to various factors including their timezone. You can also define "weekly" as being in a universal timezone (UTC or whatever other timezone makes most sense for your use-case), which simplifies the data model needed, as you'd then store the timestamps and other dates in that timezone (or derive it from UTC).